# Abrir ventana secundaria tkinter.-

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy teniendo el inconveniente de que al ejecutar el código, me abre las dos ventanas, la principal y la secundaria al mismo tiempo, sin siquiera pulsar el botón.
No sé cómo corregirlo.
Creo que el problema viene de combinar la ventana secundaria con el sistema de pestañas.

En fin, he aquí el código de lo que sería la vista:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import modelo

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Ventanas")

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

pesta0 = tkinter.Frame(notebook, background="#023d75")  # primer pestaña
pesta1 = tkinter.Frame(notebook, background="#023d75")  # segunda pestaña
pesta2 = tkinter.Frame(notebook, background="#023d75")
notebook.add(pesta0, text="Dato1")
notebook.add(pesta1, text="Historia1")
notebook.add(pesta2, text="Dato2")
root.geometry("935x755")

abrir_vtana = ttk.Button(pesta1, text="abrir ventana", command= modelo.vtana())
abrir_vtana.place(x=450, y=420)

root.mainloop()
```

Y aquí el código del archivo modelo (que es el que contiene la función a la que llama el botón):

```
from tkinter import *

def vtana():
   ventana_nueva1 = Toplevel()
   ventana_nueva1.geometry("300x200")
   ventana_nueva1.title("Ventana secundaria")
```

O sea, funciona todo. La ventana principal con sus pestañas y la ventana secundaria. Sólo que ésta última se abre sola al ejecutar nomás la vista, sin apretar siquiera el botón.
¿Cómo se arregla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un error en tu código.

La confusión está en la creación del botón:

```
abrir_vtana = ttk.Button(pesta1, text="abrir ventana", command= modelo.vtana())
```

Y es que el parámetro [`command`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#widget) espera un *callable* de python:

> command: Python **callable**. Will be called with no arguments whenever either of the increment or decrement buttons are pressed.

Básicamente un *callable* es un objeto que puede ejecutarse. Por ejemplo el *nombre* de una función.

Pero tu no estás dando el nombre de una función, tú estás invocando la función y lo que sea que esa función retorne es lo que se le está pasando como comando a la llamada.

Es decir, no es lo mismo:

```
modelo.vtana
```

Esto es un objeto *callable*, que es el método como tal

Y otra cosa es

```
modelo.vtana()
```

Al agregar los paréntesis, le indicas al interprete que quieres que se ejecute el método y quedarte con el resultado que este devuelva.

La solución, entonces, es quitar los paréntesis de la construcción del botón, pues tu quieres pasar el método, y no el resultado de su ejecución.

```
abrir_vtana = ttk.Button(pesta1, text="abrir ventana", command= modelo.vtana)
```

Obviamente, ves que se crea la ventana secundaria al inicio, porque este código que crea el botón se ejecuta al inicio.

Para ampliar un poco el tema y que recuerdes siempre que [las funciones son objetos en python](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/function-as-objects-in-python-d5215e6d1b0d), no es raro hacer algo como:

```
def miFuncion():
  print("mi función")

x = 1
print(x)
x = miFuncion
print(type(x))
x()
```

Como has visto ya, un objeto *callable*, como una función, puede pasarse como parámetro, mira esto:

```
def miFuncion():
  print("mi función")

def ejecutor(parametro):
    if callable(parametro):
        print("ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor:")
        parametro()
    else:
        print("error, no puede invocarse el parámetro")

ejecutor(miFuncion)
ejecutor(miFuncion())
```

Produce esta salida:

```
ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor:
mi función
mi función
error, no puede invocarse el parámetro
```

La función `miFunción` se ha ejecutado dos veces. La primera, porque se ha pasado la función como tal a la función `ejecutor`, y por eso se imprime primero el mensaje *ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor*.

La segunda vez, sin embargo, se ha ejecutado primero, pasa pasar el resultado a la función ejecutor, que no recibe un *callable* y por eso imprime *error, no puede invocarse el parámetro*

Si damos una vuelta más de tuerca:

```
def miOtraFuncion():
    print("mi otra función")

def miFuncion():
    print("mi función")
    return miOtraFuncion

def ejecutor(parametro):
    if callable(parametro):
        print("ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor:")
        parametro()
    else:
        print("error, no puede invocarse el parametro")

ejecutor(miFuncion)
ejecutor(miFuncion())
```

La salida es:

```
ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor:
mi función
mi función
ejecutando desde dentro de ejecutor:
mi otra función
```

¿Podrías explicar dicha salida?

Te invito a jugar con el código y a ejecutarlo paso a paso, eso te ayudará a comprender en que momento se invoca cada función.

Comment: Excelentísima explicación @jachguate, muy clara y didáctica. Te felicito y agradezco enormemente.